# Angular material autcomoplete with chips. How to correctly implement the logic of the reused component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I want to implement a reusable component based on angular-material with autofill and chips. The problem I have is that I can't find the right way to build a reactive form logic for this component. Example of a reused component:

```
<app-chips-autocomplete
 formControlName="fruits">
</app-chips-autocomplete>
```

It takes Form Control/Form ControlName, which internally I get through the inject() function. The internal implementation of the component looks something like this, the code is simplified:

```
<mat-chip-list [disabled]="disabled">
  <mat-chip
    *ngFor="let chip of chipsList">
    {{ chip.name }}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>

  <input
    #input
    matInput
    class="input"
    [formControl]="control"
    [type]="type"
    [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete" />

  <mat-autocomplete
    #autocomplete="matAutocomplete"
    (optionSelected)="onOptionSelect($event, input)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="{ options: options$ | async } as ctx">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of ctx?.options"
        [value]="option"
        [disabled]="parentDisabled && !option?.parent">
        {{ option.label }}
      </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

The Form Control that I accept inside is used to store an array of chips, but to use it on the input with which I do the search, I think, is incorrect. That is, I also use it to store an array of chips and connected to a text input field, which is why the value of FormControl changes to a string, then to an array of chips.

As a result, I want to leave FormControl only for chips, and hang the ng Model directive on the input field and use it with the ngModelChange event:

```
<input
    #input
    matInput
    ngModel
    class="input"
    [type]="type"
    [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete"
    (ngModelChange)="onInput($event)" />
```

And what I choose from the drop-down list to add at the code level in FormControl

I don't know if this solution is the right one, I want anyone with experience to tell me how best to implement this functionality.

Comment: You should not deal with the `FormControl` directly nor inject it, you need to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface where you would use `onChange` to write the array of values. The input should have its own `FormControl` which is used internally. I can tell you from experience that implementing such an autocomplete chip list form control is a total headache due to the combination of the  2 controls and underlying quirks/bugs in the Material controls.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. And which implementation would be better in your opinion?

Comment: I've only had experience with Material and am not sure of the alternatives, but I'd try anything else if I needed to do it again.